# Help me to solve this differential equation please

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\sin(xy)+xy\cos(xy)\,dx+x^2\cos(xy)\,dy=0$$
I need to check whether this ODE is exact and solve it. This kind of differential equations is new for me and I do not understand how to check exactness, previously I applied the condition $$\frac{dP}{dy}=\frac{dQ}{dx}$$ for the differential equation of the general form $$Pdx+Qdy$$ to be exact. What should I do in this case?
I also have a question regarding the solution, is it true that I need to divide both parts by $dx$? If yes, how can I do this to $\sin(xy)$?

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be $(\sin(xy)+xy\cos(xy))dx+x^2\cos(xy)dy=0$?

Comment: As you have it that seems to be a rather difficult non-linear non-homogeneous differential equation. Won't help much to know whether it is exact or not...or even to find out some integration factor. Check carefully what you have.

Comment: Yes, I’ve checked the initial assignment, maybe there is a mistake there

Comment: Most probably it is as John Wayland wrote you above, and then yes: it is an exact ODE.

Comment: Without the parentheses it makes absolutely no sense. Writing $f(x)dx+g(x)=0$ is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your ODE is indeed

$$\color{red}{\bigg(}\sin(xy)+xy\cos(xy)\color{red}{\bigg)}\,dx+x^2\cos(xy)\,dy=0$$

upon substituting $u(x)=xy(x)$ and $du=x\,dy+y\,dx$, one obtains a separable equation,

$$\left(\sin(u) + u \cos(u)\right) \, dx + x^2 \cos(u) \left(\frac{du-\frac ux\,dx}x\right) = 0 \\ 
\implies \sin(u) \, dx + x \cos(u) \, du = 0 \\
\implies \cot(u) \, du = -\frac{dx}x$$